# jQuery datepicker: disable calendar change when editing textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to disable changes in calendar layer when I edit it's textbox. Currently I when I type e.g. 2012-10-10 the calendar layer automaticaly updates to 2012-10-1. I would like to prevent changes until the user hits 'enter'.

Comment: How would you trigger the calender, if you want to block on the focus event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to simply disable the textfield and allow the user only to select dates from the datepicker. In order to disable that field you have to set `disabled` attribute as `true`.